# How to call a function provided as string parameter safely in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a situation in my **TypeScript** project where I'd like to reuse some base-logic for all methods of a class. For that, I implemented something similar to code below (heavily simplified).

```ts
interface IExample{
    getNumber(): number;
}

class Example implements IExample {
    getNumber(): number{
        return 10
    }
}

function handleClassInteraction<T>(f: string): T{
    //do a bunch of other things
    const ex = new Example()
    const res: T = ex[f]
    //do a bunch of other things
}

//calling the function would look like this:
handleClassInteraction<number>("getNumber")
handleClassInteraction<string>("getString")
```

My issue is, this is not save at all. If someone would change the function name `getNumber`, it would immediatly break the code above.
Now, is there any way to ensure that the function which is passed, is actually callable?

I played around with things like `IExample["getNumber"]` since the compiler will complain here if `getNumber` wouldn't exist but I couldn't find a way to apply it to my `handleClassInteraction` function. Further, I want to avoid `enums`

Comment: A starting point would be _not_ allowing any string, and instead restricting to actual members of the class: `keyof Example`.  But then further you'd probably want to restrict to the set of _appropriate_ keys, i.e. those for a method that takes no arguments and returns T.

Comment: Well that's the reason of my question because I want to avoid strings. However, I was forced to apply a generic approach. Anyway, your hint and someone's answer which was deleted again helped! I didn't think about using `keyof` in this context!

Comment: So you want [this](https://tsplay.dev/WoAXlN)?